# Riemann-integrable discontinuous functions

Tags: analysis, riemann-integration

Why are functions with a finite number of (removable or jump) discontinuities Riemann-integrable while Dirichlet function isn't?

(Edit)

More precisely:

$\Bbb Q \,\cap [0,1]=:(a_k)_{k\in \Bbb N}$

Define $f_n(x)$ as follows:
$$\begin{cases}
1 \quad \text{if} \,\,x\in \{a_1,\dots,a_n\} \\ 
0 \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Why are *these* functions $f_n$ Riemann-integrable?

I don't know anything about Lebesgue integration yet.

Comment: Because in any interval $[a,b]$ where $a\not=b$ there is some rational and some irrational numbers... Therefore the set of discontinuities of Dirichlet function is not of Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: @user12986714 I edited the question.

Comment: If {a} is finite, then it is Riemann integrable. If {a} is infinite, then maybe and maybe not, it depends. (Also that Lebesgue measure zero just means that "A set S is of Lebesgue measure zero if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a finite or infinite sequence of open regions I1, I2... whose union contains S  such that $\sum L(I_n) \lt \epsilon$")

Comment: @user12986714 Okay, I know "if {a} is finite etc. If {a} is infinite it depends", but I'd like to understand why... Also, what is $L(I_n)$?

Comment: On my textbook for self studying it has an entire section for that theorem; maybe you can look at [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_Theorem) or search "Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability"

Comment: @user12986714 Thanks. So there is no way of understanding it without knowing anything about Lebesgue?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with Lebesgue integral... (just the name looks scary) Also L(I) means the length of I; in one dimension for an interval [a,b] it is just b-a.

Comment: Oh okay I just didn't understand the notation then. I didn't mean Lebesgue integration, "Lebesgue measure" has "Lebesgue" in it as well . . I'll see if I understand that